# How to pause the process in MVC and resume when user select YES and should be aborted for NO

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

My application is in MVC, and database SQL. In our scenario user upload an excel file which may contain more than 100,000 records. The file is converted into data table and than uploaded to the database. Their is a validation in which it checks that whether the uploaded date is smaller than the date recorded in database. For such scenario the process should pause and we have to ask user whether they have to continue or not. If yes than the process should continue and if no than the process should be aborted.

Note:- If such condition does not occur than their will be no asking of permission.

I have many thoughts like thread sleep but am also worried by thread safety. Or dividing the whole process in two parts in two separate action result but the condition happens rarely.

Conclusion:- Thoughts are jumbled up. Need your advice, please help

Comment: Sleeping the thread is definitely a poor choice. Ideally, you'd persist the data to temporary storage and return a response that requires the client to call a different endpoint with the storage id. That endpoint would rehydrate the data and continue. If that doesn't work, you could also use in-memory caching provided that you invalidate the data after a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Can you actually specify framework you are using? MVC is a design pattern loosely followed in WPF and ASP.Net-MVC, plus can be done in any other framework like WinForms, and even WebForms.

Comment: MVC is in .NET FRAMEWORK 4.7.2